# MySQL select users who access site from different ip

Tags: mysql, sql

How should the SQL SELECT query look like if I want to select users, who accessed site from different ip?

This is a table's content:

```
id | ip        | userid | timecreated
1  | 192.0.0.1 | 1      | 111111111
2  | 192.0.0.1 | 3      | 111111111
3  | 192.0.0.2 | 1      | 111111111
4  | 192.0.0.3 | 2      | 111111111
5  | 192.0.0.2 | 2      | 111111111
```

Executing necessary SQL SELECT query should select like this:

```
id | ip        | userid | timecreated
1  | 192.0.0.1 | 1      | 111111111
3  | 192.0.0.2 | 1      | 111111111
4  | 192.0.0.3 | 2      | 111111111
5  | 192.0.0.2 | 2      | 111111111
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the users that has more than one IP:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM myTable GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

And in order to get the full records for them (like you have in your question):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE userid IN (
 SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM myTable GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `userid`s is just a simple aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having min(ip) <> max(ip);
```

If you want the detailed rows, you can use `join` or `in`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select userid
      from t
      group by userid
      having min(ip) <> max(ip)
     ) tt
     using (userid);
```